# how can i add clusters on feature layer in arc gis api for javascript?

Tags: arcgis

I want to add clusters on Feature Layer in arcgis map version 4.6 to show multiple points on same place!! as i search there is no help or sample available in arcgis for clustering.

Comment: Hi @IRTIZA, question on SO have the general format of 1. What are you trying to do? 2. What is your code that currently tries to do that? 3. What do you expect the result to be? 4. What is the actual result? Please take time to add points 2-4, right now the question is hard to answer since it does not provide a lot of information.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, basically i'm working on arcgis api 4.6 for javascript in which i'm using Feature Layer to publish services(layers)   on local host which are made in arcmap which is working fine, the problem is i want to add clusters functionality on my project now i have no idea how can i do this!!

Comment: Here is my code in which i want to add clusters, Where url is the field of source which is confidential

Comment: can't upload my code here it is bit longer comment window is not accepting it!!

Comment: Another important thing for asking questions on SO, especially if some of your code is not working is to make a minimal working example that shows the issue. Try to narrow down your code to a small part and post that. Otherwise it's impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do maps with clusters I use how exemple the links bellow:

[Basic clustering](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_clustering_basic.html)
[Point clustering](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html)

I still not tried make maps with clusters using the version 4.6 but I think that you not will have problems.

Good luck!!

Comment: Sir i already tried these examples but the problem is version variation, i want to do this clustering in 4.6 version and still not able to do this!!